# Building a JWT for Twilio's Authy using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, jwt, authy

The [No-PII user registration JWT](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users?code-sample=code-no-pii-user-registration-jwt-5&code-language=JSON&code-sdk-version=default) for adding a user in Twilio's authy requires us to build a JWT from scratch.

I tried looking everywhere on how to get a JWT created using Google Apps Script but wasn't to find the right way to make that happen. It specifically needs to be of HS256 alg.

I require the final payload to look exactly like this -

```
// Example Payload
{
  "iss": "My Authy App",
  "iat": 1554395479,
  "exp": 1554395879,
  "context": {
    "custom_user_id": "3YgAIZklGPHmwpJfIC0PDy0E7l763OF3BHZo1p2xKhY",
    "authy_app_id": "1111111"
  }
}

// Example Header
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Can someone please help me with this or perhaps point me to an appropriate article/documentation for this??

Comment: Have you tried using what's available here? - https://wtfruby.com/gas/2018/11/21/jwt-app-scripts.html
This was on my top 3 results when I googled for a `JWT using Google Apps Script` :)

Comment: Oh! This is perfect. Someone ought to make this into a library and publish it as a Gist :)

Comment: The common [oAuth library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/7fb414e2786de44231dfd7ef431032352e6c71a1/src/Service.js#L699) has jwt support. You just need to setPrivateKey() to start jwt flow. Any additional claims can be added with setAdditionalClaims. See [sample](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs)

Comment: On re-reading, you'd need ``HMAC(HS256)`` instead of ``RSA(RS256)``.  The library defaults to `RS256` and can't be changed. Though you could still use the linked code in the library as a sample.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### The general syntax for URL fetch with Google Apps Script is the following:

```
var body={
  "iss": "My Authy App",
  "iat": 1554395479,
  "exp": 1554395879,
  "context": {
    "custom_user_id": "3YgAIZklGPHmwpJfIC0PDy0E7l763OF3BHZo1p2xKhY",
    "authy_app_id": "1111111"
  };
var header={
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
};
var url='YOUR URL';
var options={
  method: 'POST',
  headers: header,
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload: JSON.stringify(body)
};
var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

According to the documentation link you provided, you might need to provide an API key. In this case, you URL should be something like `var url=basicURL+"apikey="+XXX`

I do not have a Twilio account to test it, but the sample provided above is the general procedure for Apps Script and you can find more references under the following links:

- [Working with Third-Party APIs](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis)
- [External APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external)
- [Twilio Send a SMS message](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/twilio)

  > Note that in the latter sample the payload is not in quotes.

Comment: [Last link](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/twilio) doesn't work. `jwt` requires algorithm to sign the payload.